# Counting maximum number of node traversal in a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, tree-traversal

I have a tree with N nodes.
k paths are given in the form of u,v.
Now, the problem is to find the the maximum number of times a tree node is traversed while going from u to v (not to find the node itself).

For e.g. for the following instance:

```
        1
      /   \
    2       3
  /  \
4     5
```

Paths: 1, 5; 2, 3

the ans would be 2 since node 1 is appears twice in the two paths (also true for node 2, but only the count is needed).

Enumerating all the paths is the straight forward way to go but infeasible since k <= N <= 10^5 and the naive approach is O(N^2) in worst case.

I believe there should be some way to pre-process the tree that lets find the maximum number in constant time for each path given.

Or maybe, a completely different approach is needed.

I'm looking for some pointers in the right direction. Any suggestions?
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The tree may not be binary. The only specification is it's a tree. N nodes and N-1 edges.

Comment: Is the tree binary? Are there any assumptions on the balance of the tree or can it also be a list?

Comment: Please see the Edit.